# In extjs4 Ext.MessageBox.alert() msg disalays blank window?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am working in extjs4 and i am going to print a message box on screen but it displays a blank message window.Nothig displays in it.

here is my code:-

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'App',

    appFolder: 'app',

    //controllers: ['Books'],
    requires:[
                 'Ext.window.MessageBox',
              //   'Ext.tip.*'
             ],
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            items: [
                {
                    // Explicitly define the xtype of this Component configuration.
                    // This tells the Container (the tab panel in this case)
                    // to instantiate a Ext.panel.Panel when it deems necessary
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Tab One',
                    html: 'The first tab',
                    listeners: {
                        render: function() {
                           //Ext.MessageBox.alert('Rendered One', 'Tab One was rendered.');
                             Ext.Msg.alert('hi', 'Please enter your name:');
                            //Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to do that?');
                            //alert("hi");

                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    // this component configuration does not have an xtype since 'panel' is the default
                    // xtype for all Component configurations in a Container
                    title: 'Tab Two',
                    html: 'The second tab',
                    listeners: {
                        render: function() {
                            //Ext.MessageBox.alert('Rendered One', 'Tab Two was rendered.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

and here is the message screen window

[image]

there is no any messageBox method working whats wrong in this code?
please give me some suggestions...

Comment: These links might be Helpful: http://www.c4learn.com/alert-message-box-in-extjs.html and http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-184113.html?s=550da2024ec35b4a06fc2e26241a9171

Comment: I'm not sure why you are displaying a message when a penel renders.. If you put it on the bottom of the `launch: function()`, is it working then? Is the `Ext.MessageBox.confirm` and normal `alert()` working as you expect?

Comment: I am referring code from following link http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'boxready' event ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YpuFx/)).

If output to the console:

```
...
render: function() {
    console.log(Ext.Msg.alert('hi', 'Alert message'))
}
....
```

in the 'render' listener, you will see that were incorrectly calculated the size and position of the alert:

```
...
width: NaN
x: -41
...
```